# Why package is not updated even the lifecycle script has been executed successfully in SageMaker?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, conda, amazon-sagemaker

I wanted to update pandas version in 'conda-python3' in SageMaker, I've followed the steps in this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html), and linked the new configuration to my instance, CloudWatch log shows me the script has been executed successfully, but when I restart my instance and print out the panda version, it's still showing the old version 0.24.2, I don't understand why?

[image]

This is the script in the lifecycle configuration:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'

pip install pandas

conda update pandas

source deactivate

EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not activating any conda environment such as [python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036916/sagemaker-lifecycle-configuration-for-installing-pandas-not-working).

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'

# This will affect only the Jupyter kernel called "conda_python3".
source activate python3

pip install pandas

conda update pandas

source deactivate

EOF
```